# Two different duplicate flags?

Tags: support, flags

It may be that the following question is stupid but I was not able to find an answer myself.

When clicking on "flag" below a question a "I am flagging this question because..." dialog opens. That dialog has some options. One of them reads "it is a duplicate...". However when selecting "it should be closed for another reason..." a secondary "This question doesn't belong here because it is..." dialog opens that has an option that reads "duplicate of...".

Both similar options have exactly the same description.

So what is the difference between these two duplicate-of-flags?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The 2 flags are no different.  The 2nd dialog is the exact dialog that close voters get to see.  But in an effort to encourage flaggers to flag as duplicate, the flag dialog has a more prominent option for flagging as duplicate.

Someone mentioned this previously on MSE: [New flagging dialog has a duplicate for duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196583/new-flagging-dialog-has-a-duplicate-for-duplicate)

And I referenced it in my answer to [Flagging hierarchy needs an overhaul](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214788/flagging-hierarchy-needs-an-overhaul/214809#214809)

> ### So why is duplicate duplicated in the flagging and close dialog
>
> That was a design decision that the SE team made. First, clicking duplicate from the flag dialog is just a short cut to clicking "flag > closed for another reason > duplicate". Both lead to the same place.
>
> This has been mentioned several times, but all of the duplicates point to [New flagging dialog has a duplicate for duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196583/new-flagging-dialog-has-a-duplicate-for-duplicate). There isn't an answer or even a [status-*] tag, but my belief is that they chose to give duplicates a special place in the flagging dialog to highlight the duplicate option because the current preference is posts should be closed as a duplicate if one exists before any other close reason is used.
>
> And even though they added it to the flag dialog, they can't remove it from the close dialog as users who enter the close dialog directly won't have an option to close a post as a duplicate.

Comment: Wow that is actually confusing. I wonder if that duplicate duplicate actually makes people using it more often or maybe prevents them from using it because they are (like myself) unsure about which duplicate to use and how they work :-(

Comment: @Silicomancer the organization could be better but given the way the flag dialog passes off to the close dialog, when you click "Should be closed for another reason", it is difficult to change it without maintain 2 different close dialogs for flaggers and close voters.

Comment: I see. IMHO it would be worth the effort.

Comment: @Silicomancer then that would be a feature request you can write up.  However, take a look at the previous discussions on this, specifically the 2nd question I linked.  The OP there proposes a very radical overhaul to the flag and close dialogs.  You may want to consider the discussion there before embarking on your own feature request.

Comment: After reading the links it feels like such an feature request would need to be filed for entire stackexchange, not only stackoverflow. I don't think I have enough cross-site experience for that. Also I wonder about the feature request you linked... it was better done than everything I could come up with and still it wasn't implemented so why should I request something very similar again if site developers don't share the opinion that there is a problem that needs to be fixed?