# Can we trial a line in the close vote reasons other with a link to flag as spam?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, vote-to-close, spam

A request to add a read line near the closing -> Off-Topic -> Other with a link to flag as spam.

[image]

- this addresses the confusion people have when using a custom close reason for spam
- does not interfere with UX flow
- doesn't clutter the main close vote board
- will only catch users closing as Off-topic so reduces the likelihood of people flagging as spam because the reason is on the landing page of close vote reasons
- shouldn't be expensive to develop, adding a line with a link

Along the lines of the spirit of this question [Show a warning when someone uses a custom close reason containing the word "spam"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317277/show-a-warning-when-someone-uses-a-custom-close-reason-containing-the-word-spam), without the intrusion of a pop up.

[And this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327682/3956566)

But this suggestion address concerns [such as this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327636/educating-people-to-flag-spam-and-not-vote-to-close#comment365576_327682):

> This feels like killing a fly with a jackhammer. I can't imagine how many more bad spam flags we'd get, for questionable benefit.

[image]

Can we trial this as a feature request to make sure that it doesn't unduly increase the incidence of unwarranted spam flags?

Comment: That circle was never drawn freehand.

Comment: @ArtOfCode well spotted.. *what action should we take?*

Comment: If the goal is to close spam quickly and with the correct reason then I support the idea here, but I prefer the UI proposed by @Madara. Having a trial of the feature also seems worthwhile.

Comment: @AdrianHHH well it's to delete spam quickly really, and help people find how to do that as easily as possible, without causing things to be flagged as spam unnecessarily.. *takes breath*

Comment: To clarify: I think this question is a good idea. It makes the "report as spam" facility easier to find for people who recognise that the question needs deleting but who are not thinking about the "flag as spam" facility.

Comment: This seems like an incredibly huge change to cater only for the misclicks of [less than a single user a day](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322478/4174897). Granted, it irritates me too when I see CVs on spam posts, but it's not worth introducing a UI change to _all_ 3k+ users...

Comment: What I don't understand is the upvotes on [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327682/3956566) and on [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327713/3956566) and even [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317277/show-a-warning-when-someone-uses-a-custom-close-reason-containing-the-word-spam?noredirect=1&lq=1) and not on [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327711/can-we-trial-a-line-in-the-close-vote-reasons-other-with-a-link-to-flag-as-spam?noredirect=1&lq=1) ???? *anyone know why?*

Comment: @Yvette: People legit like the design of your suggestion.  I do, too. But most of us didn't run the numbers to see if it's worth the effort.  The scale of people closing-instead-of-flagging is very small based on info in here.  Don't pay attention to the couple of the more gruff users who are being dismissive;  some folks around here, despite being competent, completely lack social graces.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler well put :)

Comment: @Kyll it's not less than a single user per day, that is the stats on people flagging with a custom reason that contains the word spam.

Answer (score 52):

As a UX developer, if your UI makes people do the wrong thing, the problem is with the UI, not with the users. Adding more notices and warnings and making them bolder, bigger, etc, won't do anything but make the UI more cluttered.

If anything, I'd much better like something like this

[image: Proposed spam close reason]

And have it map to the spam flag behind the scenes, and *after* the user had "closed" as spam, give him a gentle reminder that the correct answer is reachable through the flag menu, for future reference.

Maybe have it appear only when there's already a spam flag, maybe not, haven't given it too much thought.

The basic idea is that your UI should *flow* with the user's intentions, and not interrupt them.

Comment: @Yvette Feel free to post a new feature request and linking to this one. Personally, I don't have it well enough thought out to post something of my own, but if you have a good idea of what it should look like and behave, feel free!

Comment: Maybe later, will need to think on it also. and also see what the community thinks. I agree it's not the fault of the user.

Comment: But then this will inevitably raise the question of why there are two different ways to flag a post as spam. They look like two different actions, since they are accessed two different ways, so users will assume they are actually different. Not a very good UI design. If you want all the options in one dialog, just put all the options in one dialog. (Except that leads to cognitive overload, so don't do that either.)

Comment: Although I like this idea, is it not going to confuse? Pretty much the same impression I get from CodyGrays comment. The user clicks on close, they expect to be presented with legitimate close options. In this case, they will be presented with both types of option, close and flag.

Comment: We already have the duplicate entry in the flag dialog for duplicates.  And there have been questions as to why there are 2 duplicate flags (see [Two different duplicate flags?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272987/two-different-duplicate-flags)).  It doesn't appear to cause too much confusion

Comment: So simple, and so logical

Comment: We'd also have to make it *very clear* that deletion by spam flags incurs severe penalty for the poster. I'm afraid that if the close-vote workflow naturally leads to spam-flagging as an option, all sorts of off-topic questions will be flagged as spam. And we know how these flags can accumulate... I can even imagine a very ill-posed NullPointerException question (number 233482425323 of its kind) to be flagged first by grumpy veterans, then by clueless newbies.

Comment: I think this is a great idea. In my opinion, it's the best approach given the current system.  Isn't the problem that people don't know what flagging is or how to properly handle spam and so they close vote? If that's the case, then, the handful of people that could be confused about having this option in multiple places is a small price to pay for a better way to handle dangerous content.

Comment: This seems like it would have a ***huge*** impact over moderation only to care about [less than a single user a day](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322478/4174897). There may be a lot more erroneous spam flags and more confusion over what the difference between flags and close votes are. Also, I as an experience user really don't want any of this spam business in my close votes menu only so that a handful of clueless users can see it when they misclick.

Comment: This. Take away the "close vote" vs "flag" distinction. It's pointless.

Comment: @Kyll  Between 15 and 20% of all posts that were flagged as spam also have at least 1 close vote.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit But not all flags lead to closure...

Comment: @immibis: Not all close votes lead to closure. And I'm not necessarily saying they should change how it's all handled behind the scenes, but from a GUI perspective the distinction only fosters confusion and for no good reason.

Answer (score 26):

I'm going to strongly oppose this, for a few reasons:

1. I still haven't seen this cause any real *harm*, just irritation at people not doing things just right. If we were having real, demonstrable *issues* with people closing spam (Yahoo! Answers style), then I might be persuaded - but as is, I haven't seen spam get more than a close vote or two.

   Strong meh on that being a real problem.
2. Stack Overflow already gets enough misguided spam flags, more of them from higher rep users than I'd like to admit. Implementing either the suggestion in the question or [in Madara's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327713/1849664) would almost certainly increase the number of bad flags we have to decline.

   I'm willing to do more work declining spam flags if (and only if) we get something in return. I haven't seen enough scenarios where this would make a tangible difference.

Comment: Then we should be educating users how to user the site, or make the UX clearer. How hard can it be, it's a site for programmers?? O>O

Comment: Just curious, do you handle a lot of spammy posts? Because I rarely see those on SO

Comment: @Yvette We don't necessarily need to do *anything* - we need to establish a problem before deciding a solution. Also, I'm not saying that implementing it would be hard - I'm saying that declining all the bad spam flags this would generate would be annoying, with no benefit that I can see.

Comment: @AlonEitan [Decent number](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&body=&username=&why=&site=1&feedback=true+positive&reason=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&commit=Search), but a drop in the bucket compared to SO's overall volume.

Comment: @AlonEitan, SE itself blocks a [TON of spam](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237848/anti-spam-blocking-questions-whose-bodies-end-with-a-raw-hyperlink/237882#237882). There are community projects, such as [SmokeDetector](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229072/186281) (note, Undo and I both assist in development) that allows the spam that does get through.

Comment: @Undo I agree declining spam flags is not good, but people are voting to close and spam flagging (usually) with good will, if people who have been active in the site for a while cannot understand how to use the site intuitively, then I regard that as a poor UX

Comment: @Yvette It *might* be poor UX (I'd like to see hard numbers on how often this happens before even calling it that), but if it's not causing issues we shouldn't be spending dev time and moderator time on it. There are tons of little glitches in the moderator tools that actually cause *mistakes* that I'd rather see dev time spent on.

Comment: OMG, it's amazing what's going on behind the scenes. Thanks

Comment: A [related study](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322478/189134) by bluefeet a few months ago

Comment: well we could trial it Undo and that way we'd know for sure if there was any statistical damage re increase in false spam flags. That wouldn't cause harm would it?

Comment: @Yvette It'd use dev time. I wouldn't have an issue with trying it, except that I haven't been given a reason to believe it'll make a real material difference for the better

Comment: @Undo bluefeet's answer is good.

Comment: Between 15 and 20% of all posts that were flagged as spam also have at least 1 close vote.

Answer (score 20):

As you mentioned, [I looked at a similar request a few months ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322478/426671) and declined that request because there was too much work for so few posts.

I quickly pulled some numbers this morning to see how many posts flagged as spam (and that flag was marked helpful) are also getting close votes. Here is what I found.

```
month    # Spam Flags   # w/ Close Votes  % w/ Close Votes
-------  -------------- ---------------- -----------------
2016-07   290            39              13.4
2016-06  1046           176              16.8
2016-05   980           122              12.4
2016-04  1088           166              15.2
2016-03  1118           180              16.1
2016-02  1103           202              18.3
2016-01  1295           256              19.7
```

I was curious about what close votes are being added to these posts, so here is a breakdown of the close reasons:

```
month   # Spam & Close Posts Dups OffTopic Migrate Other SU SF Typo Debug Rec Unclear Broad Opinion
------- -------------------- ---- -------- ------- ----- -- -- ---- ----- --- ------- ----- -------
2016-07  39                  1    12       0       11     1 1  0     4     3   16      7     2
2016-06 176                  1    56       1       57     6 3  1    16    34   62     45    16
2016-05 122                  1    50       0       45    12 1  0     8    24   40     22    10
2016-04 166                  2    53       1       53     6 4  2    14    26   74     37    15
2016-03 180                  0    61       1       52    13 3  0    13    31   70     30    21
2016-02 202                  1    79       4       64    16 2  0    15    25   71     34    18
2016-01 256                  2    91       3       99    19 5  3    31    39  104     55    29
```

The close reasons are all over the map, but it appears that most users are flagging or voting to close spam posts as unclear what you're asking.

About 15% of all posts with a helpful spam flag also receives a close vote and I honestly don't think this is a huge problem because the posts are still being removed.

While I understand what you are trying to do, I don't think that we'd alter the existing dialog in the way suggested by your post or by [Madara's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327713/426671). If we're going to tweak the dialog specifically for spam, then I'd think we'd look at doing a complete overhaul on it and that's not a priority at this time.  I'm going to [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) this request.

Comment: The really interesting statistic would be how many people who voted to close *didn't flag*. That's the real issue, if present. Few close votes *in addition to* spam flags is entirely harmless.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm reading the table correctly but... between 15 and 20% of all posts that were flagged as spam *also* have at least 1 close vote?

Comment: @Braiam That is correct - these are for posts with a helpful spam flag and at least one close vote.

Comment: That is... worrying. I think we may need the stats about users that closevoted but didn't flagged as spam, as @AndrasDeak suggest.

Comment: @Braiam, Why? The posts are still getting removed as spam. On SO, those posts rarely last more than a few minutes. In the time it takes to get 6 spam flags, it manages to pick up a few close votes as well. According to the numbers laid out in the [current featured question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327636/educating-people-to-flag-spam-and-not-vote-to-close?cb=1), those flag numbers line up pretty well with the Close vote/Delete vote route.

Comment: @Andy undesirable behavior proliferates if left unchecked.

Comment: As I said @Braiam I don't think this is a big enough issue at this time to devote resources to it.  That being said, it could be something we address if/when we do an overhaul of the flag/close dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it dawned on me last night that a custom reason was not always being used and I was wondering what reason was being used. So you answered that. Thanks again for your efforts.

Comment: Shouldn't the numbers from this month be normalised (that is, multiplied by 2.6)? Or perhaps to per time unit, e.g. spam flags per day.